# Play Resumable Upload Permissions Error

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, resumablejs

I can't find the cause of this error that occurs when I upload a file using Play Scala and Resumable.js:

> Thread "application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3": controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:44)
>
> Some(resumableInfo) from resumableParams =>: ResumableInfo(authorName,1048576,1430174,1430174-AllegrofromDuetinCMajormp3,Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3,Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3,/Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp)

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:408) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:407) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
[error] application - 

! @6p27df40a - Internal server error, for (POST) [/resumable] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:266) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:262) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:408) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:407) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
```

The code that makes the file is like this...

def checkIfUploadFinished: Boolean = {
    val count: Int = Math.ceil(resumableTotalSize.toDouble / resumableChunkSize.toDouble).toInt
    1.until(count) foreach { i: Int =>
      if (!uploadedChunks.contains(i)) return false
    }

```
val file: File = new File(resumableFilePath)
val newPath: String = file.getAbsolutePath.substring(0, file.getAbsolutePath.length - ".temp".length)
file.renameTo(new File(newPath))
true
```

}

Re-running it gives me this...

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:46) ~[classes/:2.4.6]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:22) ~[classes/:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:408) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:407) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
[error] application - 

! @6p2c3mpkb - Internal server error, for (POST) [/resumable] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:266) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:262) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:46) ~[classes/:2.4.6]
    at controllers.Resumable$$anonfun$doPost$1.apply(Resumable.scala:22) ~[classes/:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:408) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:407) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, you're trying to save the file to `/Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3.temp`, and you don't have permission to open that file.  Which is a good thing, allowing users to upload any arbitrarily named file to your root file system would be a serious security issue.  In fact, it probably is a serious security issue anyway, since they could choose any file name, eg `/etc/passwd`, and next thing you know, they've created new user accounts for themselves on your system.

You should select a file name in a temporary directory, and avoid using the same file name as they've sent you, as that avoids a whole range of potential security problems.  A better solution is to use a hash of the file name combined with the users user name.  So the file you should use would be:

```
new File(someTempDirectory, username + "-" + file.getName.hashCode())
```